# Gamma function, showing identity of terms

Tags: gamma-function

How can I show this identity?
$$t^{a+h-1}e^{-t}=t^{a-1}e^{-t}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{ \log(t)^k}{k!}h^k $$
Anyone can give me hint?

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Now $t^h = \exp(\log(t^h)) = \exp(h\log t) \ldots$